# Logic behind updating object List using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of POCO objects, why is it that the following code:

```
elements.Where(x => x.Param1 == "M").Select(x => x.Param2= "").ToList();
```

(TL;DR; sets param2 = "" on every element which param1 equals M)

updates the enumerable while this one:

```
elements.Where(x => x.Param1 == "M").Select(x => x.Param2= "");
```

does not update it?

Notice that i'm doing neither  `elements = elements.Where...` nor `var results = elements.Where...`

Comment: Your query won't be executed until you call ToList,ToArray or loop over it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Comment: It Enumerates only when you are calling `toList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second code snippet without `ToList` is just a query. You need to iterate to actually execute it. Calling `ToList` executes the original query and since in your `Select` you are modifying a property of an object, you see the effect *(or a side effect)* in your original list. It is related to **parameter passing in C#**. Since your lambda expression in `Select` is an anonymous method which is receiving a parameter object of the list. Later when you modify one of it's property you see the effect.

Similarly if you try to set the object to `null` you will not see the side effect.

```
.Select(x => x = null).ToList();
```